# Looking for a way to remove duplicate entries with variable information

Tags: microsoft-excel, deduplication

I am trying to remove duplicates having variable information.

- Column F = delete time
- Column Q = recipient code
- Column R = recipient address

I need to remove duplicates that match on row information. What defines a duplicate is column F, which can vary by up to 15 minutes. The difficulty for me is that there are hundreds of line items that match Column Q & R. So I sort by column F and then I am forced to look line-item by line-item at columns Q & R, which is very time consuming. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you include some sample data for us to work with?

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible method.*

**First is**, built-in command should work.

- Select columns one by one (since are not in 
  continuation) and from **D**ata TAB, choose 
  **R**emove duplicates.
- On the Remove duplicates window you may Check 
  and Un-check columns.
- Click **O**K and it should remove the duplicates 
  from the selected columns.

[image]

---

**Second method is**, VBA Macro, is faster and better.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateSpecificColumns() 

Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 4, 7), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- To open the VB Editor, either hit **Alt+F11** or **R**ight Click the Sheet TAB.
- Then click **V**iew Code.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code as standard module.
- **S**ave the Workbook as **M**acro enabled.
- **R**UN the Marco.

**N.B.**

*In above code `Array(1, 4, 7)` represents Column `1st, 4th & 7th`, you need to adjust them as your need.*

*`Header:=xlYes` should `Header:=XlNo`, if column has no header.*